# Pandas dataframe Groupby with Min,Max and Sum

Tags: pandas, group-by, sum, min

I have the following dataframe at AID level and I would like to `Group By` on CID with `min` priority, `max` Ind values and also calculate the `sum` for amount field

Dataframe

```
AID   CID   priority amount    Ind
100   C100     1       50       1
200   C100     2       100      0
300   C300     5       300      0
400   C300     3       200      0
500   C300     4       150      0
```

Desired Dataframe

```
CID  Priority   amount   Ind
C100    1       150       1
C300    3       650       0
```

I tried this

```
df2=df.groupby(['CID']).min('Priority')

Error: method object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(
    df.groupby("CID", as_index=False).agg(
        {"priority": "min", "Ind": "max", "amount": "sum"}
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
    CID  priority  Ind  amount
0  C100         1    1     150
1  C300         3    0     650
```